# Exclude certain argument from a stub

Tags: rspec

If I want to stub out a User instance' `has_law?` method I do can do this:

```
allow(user).to receive(:has_law?).with(anything).and_return(true)
```

This will return `true` no matter what arguments are passed to `has_law?`.

But what should I do if I want to give it any argument APART from, say `:foo`?

How do I do this?

Pseudo code:

```
allow(user).to receive(:has_law?).with(anything_except(:foo)).and_return(true)
#=> undefined method `anything_except'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own matcher or use the following (not tested):

```
allow(user).to receive(:has_law?) do |arg|
  expect(arg).not_to eq(:foo)
  true
end
```